# How do you mock a "from ... import" in Python unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

My function uses a non-existent library:

```
from a.b import c
def func():
    d = c()
```

How do I mock c? So far I tried these methods, but not sure why it doesn't work:

```
mock_a = Mock(name="a")
mock_a.b = Mock(name="b")
mock_d = Mock(name="d")
mock_a.b.c = MagicMock(return_value=mock_d)
sys.modules["a"] = mock_a
```

and also tried

```
mock_ab = Mock(name="a.b")
mock_d = Mock(name="d")
mock_ab.c = MagicMock(return_value=mock_d)
sys.modules["a.b"] = mock_ab
```

Comment: Why doesn't the library exists? In my understanding if a library required for a test is missing, the test should fail (or error).

Comment: @KlausD. The library doesn't exist on my computer

Comment: Then you have to install it. It is not helpful to mock out tests that don't work for some reason. You could just delete the tests then.

Comment: @KlausD. What if this program only runs in specific environments/OS? I can't do any of that

Answer (score 0):

I will do something like this.

Suppose my test are in a file `tests.py` and the file I want to test is `demo.py`. Both file are in the same directory.

**demo.py**

This file contains the `c` function I want to mock during unit test.

```
from a.b import c
def func():
    d = c()
```

**test.py**

In the test, I will mock the method like this

```
# import patch from mock package
def test_demo_file():
    with patch("demo.c") as c_mock:
         # do what ever you want to do with c_mock. c_mock should mock the method c in demo.py file.
```

**Note**: `demo.c` means the file are in the same directory. If the files were in different directory, then `demo.c` will the import path of the file, means, it will be similar to how you will import the file in your test file.